# Xcode console, clear screen programmatically

Tags: xcode

I'm kinda new to Xcode and even programming.

From Xcode, in my code, how do I show the console and clear the screen?

I know I could do it with the Xcode preferences, but I would like to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - leave out the last activate part if you wish Xcode to stay on top of your app:

```
bool ClearXCodeDebuggerConsole()
{
    NSString *const scriptText = @"\
tell application \"System Events\"\n\
set currentapp to the name of the current application\n\
end tell\n\
tell application \"Xcode\" to activate\n\
tell application \"System Events\"\n\
keystroke \"r\" using {command down, control down, option down}\n\
end tell\n\
tell application currentapp to activate\n\
return true";

    NSAppleScript *script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptText] autorelease];
    [scriptText release];
    NSDictionary *dictError = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&dictError];

    if (!result) return false;
    if ([result booleanValue] != YES) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Accurate for AppKit (OS X), but unfortunately not so for iOS UIKit.  Specifically, the iOS library #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> as derived from the AppKit documentation @import Foundation does not support NSAppleScript and NSAppleEventDescriptor. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/

Answer (score 1):

You can display the console window by pressing Shift + Command + R. You can clear the console window by pressing Control + Option + Command + R. Both options are available from the Run menu.

Comment: Thank you for helping out here, but this one did not help me programmatically.